# Failed to get main window after 30 retries: kAXErrorServerNotFound

Tags: xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing, xcode9-beta

I have a suite of 26 tests. Sometimes some tests, any test, will fail with the following error:

```
Test Case ...
    t =     0.00s     Start Test at 2017-06-21 13:41:15.265
    t =     0.00s     Set Up
    t =     0.11s     Launch com.company.MyApp
    t =     4.06s         Wait for app to idle
    t =    10.27s             Unable to monitor animations
    t =    16.45s             Unable to monitor event loop
    t =    17.67s     Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for com.company.MyApp
    t =    23.84s         Assertion Failure: <unknown>:0: Failure getting snapshot Error Domain=XCTDaemonErrorDomain Code=12 "Failed to get main window after 30 retries: kAXErrorServerNotFound (see <rdar://problem/15530121>)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to get main window after 30 retries: kAXErrorServerNotFound (see <rdar://problem/15530121>)}
    t =    23.85s         Tear Down
```

The tests do not show as failed in the report when using Xcode 8 but they do when using Xcode 9. With Xcode 9 the problem is similar but the logs different.

```
t =     0.00s Start Test at 2017-06-22 14:17:00.716
t =     0.08s Set Up
t =     0.18s Open com.company.MyApp
t =     0.26s     Launch com.company.MyApp
t =     3.39s         Wait for com.company.MyApp to idle
t =     9.58s             Unable to monitor animations
t =    15.76s             Unable to monitor event loop
t =    16.90s Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 18003
t =    23.17s Tap "More" Button
t =    23.17s     Wait for com.company.MyApp to idle
t =    29.41s         Unable to monitor animations
t =    35.59s         Unable to monitor event loop
t =    35.61s     Find the "More" Button
t =    35.61s         Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 18003
t =    41.92s         Wait for com.company.MyApp to idle
t =    48.16s             Unable to monitor animations
t =    54.34s             Unable to monitor event loop
t =    55.36s         Find the "More" Button (retry 1)
t =    55.37s             Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 18003
t =    61.69s             Wait for com.company.MyApp to idle
t =    67.92s                 Unable to monitor animations
t =    74.10s                 Unable to monitor event loop
t =    75.12s         Find the "More" Button (retry 2)
t =    75.12s             Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 18003
t =    81.44s             Wait for com.company.MyApp to idle
t =    87.66s                 Unable to monitor animations
t =    93.86s                 Unable to monitor event loop
t =    94.00s Assertion Failure: report.feature:11: Failed to get main window after 30 retries: kAXErrorServerNotFound (see <rdar://problem/15530121>)
t =    94.21s Find the Window
t =    94.21s     Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 18003
t =   101.35s     Find the Window (retry 1)
t =   101.35s         Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 18003
t =   108.53s     Find the Window (retry 2)
t =   108.53s         Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 18003
t =   114.79s Assertion Failure: report.feature:10: Failed to get main window after 30 retries: kAXErrorServerNotFound (see <rdar://problem/15530121>)
t =   114.79s Tear Down
```

The screenshots in the report show that the application is launched and seems idle.

**Update**

I reproduced the issue in a [sample project](https://github.com/SponsorPay/XCTestIssue) that is a simple application with a tab bar view controller.

**Update**

There seem to be a known issue in the release notes of Xcode 9 Beta 6 regarding this

> xcodebuild test can intermittently fail with ‘Domain=XCTestManagerErrorDomain Code=12
>   “Failed to get main window after 30 retries”’. (29122169)
>
> **Workaround**: Try the test again.

Let's just hope this get fixed before the final release of Xcode 9

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this *exact* same issue on **Xcode 8.3.2** — sad to hear that Xcode 9 beta hasn't fixed that yet :(

The only reliable fix so far has been *resetting* the iOS Simulator device(s). For instance:

```bash
osascript -e 'tell application "Simulator" to quit'
xcrun simctl erase all
```

If you know your device ID, you can reset just that instead:

```bash
xcrun simctl erase DEVICE_ID
```

(It goes without saying that you can wrap these commands in a simple *shell script* and run it from your Terminal when this issue pops up.)

Comment: Thanks. I'm running my tests on a device though. Any solution for that?

Comment: Hmm... you could try deleting the app (and UI tests) from the device. But this hasn't always worked for me either in the past.